How to update a Text Widget with Future String
I am running Flutter on Windows.
I have a default folder with the default folder label. After I start the program, click a button, pick a different folder, then I need to see the folder label updated to reflect the new folder selected. Currently, this is not working.
Here is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Demo',theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),home: const MyHomePage(),);
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with ChangeNotifier {
  String? myDirectory = 'C:/Users/Home/Desktop';

  Future<String> getFolder() async {
    String? myfolder='';
    myfolder == await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
    return myfolder;
  }

  String? updateFolderLabel()  {
    String abc = '';
    getFolder().then((result){
      abc = result;
    });
    notifyListeners();
    return abc;
  }

  String? getFolderLabel()  {
   if (updateFolderLabel()!.isEmpty) return myDirectory;
   if (updateFolderLabel()!.isNotEmpty) return updateFolderLabel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      Widget myfolderLabel = Text(getFolderLabel()!);
     Widget myButton = SizedBox(width: 200,height: 80,child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: [
            Expanded(child: TextButton(onPressed: updateFolderLabel,style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blue,side: BorderSide(width: 1.0)),child: Text("Open Folder",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))))]));
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Hello Flutter')),        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext ctx, BoxConstraints constraints){
         return Container(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
           myfolderLabel,
           myButton,
        ])));
       })
      ));
  }
}


This question is similar to: What is a Future and how do I use it?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Firstly: To update the UI you have to use the setState(() {}); function.
Secondly: you didn't implement the functions properly, here is how I did it, and it's working:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with ChangeNotifier {
  String myDirectory = 'C:/Users/Home/Desktop'; //This is the default
  String? currentDirectory = 'C:/Users/Home/Desktop'; // This the one we change initialized by 'C:/Users/Home/Desktop'

  Future<String?> getFolder() async {
    String? myFolder = '';
    myFolder = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
    //it was: ==  which is wrong.
    return myFolder;
  }

  Future<String?> updateFolderLabel() async {
    currentDirectory = await getFolder();
    notifyListeners();
    setState(() {}); // update the UI when we update the label
    return currentDirectory;
  }

  String? getFolderLabel() {
    /*if (updateFolderLabel().isEmpty) return myDirectory;
    if (updateFolderLabel().isNotEmpty) return getFolderLabel(); //here you were calling the function twice, which is inconvenient.
    */
    if (currentDirectory.isEmpty) return myDirectory;
    // else:
    return currentDirectory;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget myFolderLabel = Text(getFolderLabel()!);
    Widget myButton = SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        height: 80,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: updateFolderLabel,
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue, side: const BorderSide(width: 1.0)),
                      child: const Text("Open Folder", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))))
            ]));
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Hello Flutter')),
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext ctx, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  myFolderLabel,
                  myButton,
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I hope that helps.

This is better, but the old problem is still there: currentDirectory is the Future. getFolderLabel() cannot return a Future. It should return a string b/c I cannot use Text(Future). I should use Text(String). I need to convert Future into String. I am not sure how to best tackle this.

What you mean by currentDirectory is the Future. Of course getFolderLabel() cannot return Future, do you want it to do that? so you want to do this: Text(Future converted to String)? If yes, the only way is to put it in Future Builder or do it like I already did.

Future<String?> updateFolderLabel() uses await getFolder() which returns future string which means that I can't use it in Text(string). I need to do convert: Text(Future to String), but there is one catch. I want show default directory path in Text(default path string) and show Text(future convert to String after I pick a folder. I am not sure what's the best solution here.
